# inserting data from another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

create user TESTING identified by "Test";

```
grant connect, resource to TESTING;
grant dba to TESTING; 

connect TESTING/Test;

set define off;


create table airport_final
(
iata_code varchar2(3),
city_code varchar2(3),
city_name nvarchar2(24),
country_code varchar2(2),
country_name nvarchar2(33),
no_of_airports number(1),
airport_code varchar2(3),
city_with_country nvarchar2(61),
airport_name nvarchar2(80)
);

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('YVE','YVE', 'Vernon', 'CA', 'Canada');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('ZZW','ZZW', 'Day Trip Mystery', 'PG', 'Australia');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('VRA','VRA', 'Varadero', 'CU', 'Cuba');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('VRO','VRA', 'Varadero', 'CU', 'Cuba');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('BOL','BOL', 'Ballykelly', 'PG', 'United Kingdom');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('BMV','BMV', 'Buon Ma Thuot', 'PG', 'Vietnam');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('WBI','WBU', 'Boulder', 'US', 'United States');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('WBU','WBU', 'Boulder', 'US', 'United States');

INSERT INTO airport_final(iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name) 
VALUES ('WHH','WBU', 'Boulder', 'US', 'United States');

commit;

select iata_code, city_code, city_name, country_code, country_name from airport_final where city_code='VRA';

create table city(
city_code varchar2(3),
country_code varchar2(3),
city varchar2(24)
);
```

I have inserted data from CSV file to oracle table `airport_final` and want to insert particular columns into table city by using this statement

```
SQL> insert
  into city(city_code, country_code,city)
  with t as (
             select  distinct c.country_code,
                              a.city_name,
                              a.city_code
               from  airport_final a,
                     city c
               where c.city_code = a.city_code
            )
  select  
          city_code,
          country_code,
          city_name
    from  t
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16  
0 rows created.
```

This statement is not inserting data
Please advise how can I insert specific column(S) data from another table

Best Regards

Comment: You are joining to `city` in your query but you haven't populated it yet. No rows can come out of `t`. As I mentioned in your other post, you are going to have to clean this data up manually. Take your airport data, pop it into Excel, and manually resolve conflicting city_code/country_code/city_name assocations. When its' clean, script insert statements and populate `city`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *insert* query uses join between these two tables, which suggests that there already might exists some rows in the target, `city` table. If that's so, how about another approach - `merge`?

If there already are some rows, perform update; otherwise, perform insert:

```
SQL> merge into city a
  2    using (select distinct f.city_code, f.country_code, f.city_name
  3           from airport_final f
  4          ) b
  5    on (a.city_code = b.city_code)
  6  when matched then update set
  7    a.country_code = b.country_code,
  8    a.city = b.city_name
  9  when not matched then insert
 10    (city_code, country_code, city) values
 11    (b.city_code, b.country_code, b.city_name);

6 rows merged.

SQL> select * from city;

CITY_CODE  COUNTRY_CODE    CITY
---------- --------------- ------------------------
ZZW        PG              Day Trip Mystery
VRA        CU              Varadero
YVE        CA              Vernon
WBU        US              Boulder
BMV        PG              Buon Ma Thuot
BOL        PG              Ballykelly

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [the old-fashioned]:

```
insert into city( city_code, country_code, city )
select [distinct] 
  a.city_code
, c.country_code
, a.city_name
from  airport_final a
inner join city c
   on a.city_code = c.city_code
```

Comment: `select [distinct]
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
`

Comment: Throwing error on `select [distinct]`

Comment: Either remove the square braces around the keyword distinct or, better, still get rid of it completely because, IMHO, using "select distinct" almost always indicates a problem the the source data [or data structures].

Comment: When I remove square braces then its taking duplicate records and by removing braces the query produces same results that I posted in my question

Comment: "Duplicate" in what respect?  `distinct a, b, c` is effectively the same as `group by a, b, c order by a, b, c` (and performs about as "well").  If you want to remove duplication within a single column, you need to explain further - and, again, suggests a problem with your table structures.